# Can "still" and "yet" be used interchangeably when placed at beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> The three picked up their chopsticks and started on the food. The
> scene seemed strangely normal to Naomi. It was as if everything were OK,
> and her mom were perfectly healthy. In fact, she looked more lively
> and energetic than Naomi remembered. The whole illness issue seemed like
> a distant, bad dream. Something that belonged to another reality.
>
> **Still**, Naomi couldn't take the thought out of her head, so she decided
> to ask.

If I changed **still** for **yet**, would the sentence mean the same thing?

Comment: “Naomi couldn’t take the thought out of her head” does not sound right to me. I understand what you mean, except I don’t know what thought you’re referring to, but I would at the very least change ‘take’ to ‘get’—or even better use ‘shake’: “Still, Naomi couldn’t shake [whatever thought it is], so she decided to ask”.

Comment: In your example I would say either "*Even so...*" or "*And yet...*".  '*Still*' could work in spoken English with the right intonation, but reads oddly (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  What first comes to my mind is that, even though they are very similar, *yet* connotes contradiction, whereas *still* carries the notion of defiance.

Let me view it from a different aspect.

*Yet* entails an element of surprise by the contrasting circumstances. *Yet* is like saying to your chum: "So, yeah, that's all nice and good... but check this out."

*Still* is more in the vein of: "So, yeah, that's that... but never you mind that."

It's a tiny difference, but it's a difference in the level of deductive capabilities that you, as the author, expect your audience to have. If they sense you consider them not capable enough of figuring out things without your solicitious guidance, and that you therefore opt for "yet" (*... —Oh, yeah? What could it be?*) instead of "still" (*...  —Yeah, yeah, go on, I follow you.*), they might turn their backs on you. And stop reading your story.

Comment: So *yet* is a better option for the example above?

Comment: I'm not able to answer that. I don't know the prior context of this. You have to put yourself in the mind of your readers. But, no, I'd be much more likely to go with 'still'.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, *still* means ‘nevertheless, all the same’. *Yet* can have a similar meaning, but not when used in this way. *Still* can stand on its own at the beginning of a sentence and affect its interpretation, but *yet* cannot.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are proscribing starting a sentence with *yet*?If so, then that's a problem similar to ending a sentence with a preposition.Look how tall of a deck is stacked against your stance: [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106901/yet-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence) [2](http://grammarmadeclear.blogspot.com/2010/05/can-i-start-sentence-with-and-yet-or.html) [3](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=64399) [4](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/92430-wrong-use-yet-start-sentence.html). 1st google results for _can start sentence with yet_

Comment: OK, this one seems to be on your side: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all, only that you can't use it as a sentence adverb in the way that you can use _still_ as a sentence adverb.

Comment: _And yet_ at the beginning works much better than _yet_ alone; with _and_, it works more like _still_. Note that _still_ is not an NPI, whereas _yet_ is: _Bill is still here/*Bill is yet here/??Bill is here yet/Bill is here still_ vs _Bill isn't still here/Bill still isn't here/Bill isn't here yet/yet here._