# Should I use "still" or "yet" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> The atmosphere had relaxed a bit. Still/Yet, I couldn't stop thinking how
>   strange it was to watch my brother being insecure.

Which on is the correct choice? I often get confused about which one to use. They seem interchangeable to me most of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128831/can-still-and-yet-be-used-interchangeably-when-placed-at-beginning-of-a-sent

Comment: indeed a duplicate of your own question. One small addition: still in this kind of usage is usually followed by a pause (i.e. a comma), yet 'yet' often isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Subscrioption-Only LDOCE:

> **Yet** is used to say that something has not happened or a situation has not started to exist, or to ask if something has happened:
>
> *It isn't time to go yet.*
>
> *Have you seen him yet?*

---

> **Still* is used to say that an earlier situation has not changed:
>
> *This system of naming is still used today* (NOT *yet used today*).
>
> *I still don't understand.*

So I'd say in that sentence it's better to use *still*, rather than *yet*, because you had been thinking, and it hasn't changed so far, and you are *still* thinking.

Comment: 'still' and 'yet' both have more meanings than that

Comment: Yes, but this is the grammatical point to distinguish when to use what. The rest of meanings are of course accessible in any dictionaries out there. (:

Comment: That only applies to specific meanings. From longman: still - 'in spite of what has just been said or done', 'The hotel was terrible. Still, we were lucky with the weather' yet - 'used to introduce a fact, situation, or quality that is surprising after what you have just said', 'She does not speak our language and yet she seems to understand'

Answer (score 2):

They are technically interchangeable, but *yet* is a little more old-fashioned and formal. Given the tone of your sentence, I would use *still*.

Also, it should be *relaxed*, not *relax*, and *see* would be more appropriate than *watch*.

Answer (score 1):

Both *yet* and *still* are *adversatives,* i.e., words used to indicate or acknowledge a kind of dialectical tension between sentences or clauses, as representing two more or less opposing viewpoints. This category also includes *but, however, [al]though, nonetheless,* and *nevertheless.* Many of these words have other functions and senses as well, notably including *yet* and *still,* but I believe this question deals with their shared adversative sense.

In this sense, *yet* functions as a [coordinating conjunction](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/coordinating-conjunctions.html), *still* as a [conjunctive adverb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/list-of-conjunctive-adverbs.html).

Because of that difference, they are punctuated a little differently. In the case where a period precedes the word (so that *sentences* are being contrasted), *still* takes a following comma more often and comfortably than *yet* does (though you can go either way with either). Thus—

- The atmosphere had relaxed a bit. Still, I couldn't stop thinking how strange it was to watch my brother being insecure.
- The atmosphere had relaxed a bit. Yet I couldn't stop thinking how strange it was to watch my brother being insecure.

If a period does *not* precede, *yet* works fine with just a comma or nothing at all before it (and nothing after it, either), while *still* is happier with a semicolon before and a comma after.

- The atmosphere had relaxed a bit, yet I couldn't stop thinking how strange it was to watch my brother being insecure.
- The atmosphere had relaxed a bit; still, I couldn't stop thinking how strange it was to watch my brother being insecure.